# Can I have a variable in CPLEX that is not part of the objective function?

Tags: python, cplex

I'm trying to solve my MIP with CPLEX (python). I'm new to CPLEX (for the record also new to MIP). I have my objective function containing two variables so this implies I only have to declare two variables right? 
e.g.:

```
first_scene = list(cpx.variables.add(.....
last_scene = list(cpx.variables.add(.....
```

My problem is I have a constraint that uses other variable thus I don't understand how to construct this contraint. More specific what I should use as indices.

```
## Constraint: Each scene j can be assigned to at most one shooting day:
## sum(k in shooting_days) presence[j][k] <=1 || for each scene
for j in range(number_of_scenes):
    cpx.linear_constraints.add(
        lin_expr=[cplex.SparsePair(
            ind=??, val=??)],
        senses=["L"],
        rhs=[1.0])
```

I define presence_matrix earlier as:

```
presence_matrix = np.zeros(shape=(number_of_scenes,int(number_of_shooting_days)))
```

Comment: You have to create variables for every variable in the model. Variables that are not "in the objective" implicitly have an objective coefficient of zero.

Comment: If you haven't already, I'd recommend that you take a close look at the example programs that are included with CPLEX when you install the software. If `COSDIR` is the location where you installed CPLEX Optimization Studio, then you should find the examples under `<COSDIR>\cplex\examples`.

Comment: Can i share my project with u? I have written out the MIP and I could share my code if u would be willing to take a look at it.

Comment: I have based my python implementation on the facility example provided in the examples, but I have managed to confuse myself pretty hard

Comment: It is absolutely normal and expected that a model in CPLEX or any of the other solvers will have only a small proportion of the variables in the objective function. In most models there will be many variables and constraints defining e.g. the structure of the problem, but which do not appear in the objective.

Comment: I figured! I explicitly give 0 as val with it to accomplish that, right?

Comment: Yes, if you set the objective coefficients to zero (0.0) explicitly this will add the variables to the model and they will not be considered in the objective. Also, when you call [variables.add](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.VariablesInterface-class.html#add) the `obj` argument is optional (the objective coefficients will default to zero (0.0)).